# Free Electron Galerkin FEM

Tags: partial-differential-equations, complex-numbers, heat-equation

### SCHRODINGER’S EQUATION

$$-ih u_{t}(x,y,z,t) = \frac{h^2}{2m} u_{xx}(x,y,z,t)+ \frac{e^2}{r}u(x,y,z,t)$$
The potential $\frac{e^2}{r}$ is a variable coefficient.
So, let’s take the free Schrodinger equation $$-i u_{t}(x,y,z,t) = \frac{1}{2} u_{xx}(x,y,z,t)$$
in three dimensions, where we’ve set $h = m = 1$ and dropped the potential term. It looks like the diffusion equation.

\begin{align*}
-i u_{t}(x,y,z,t) &= \frac{1}{2} u_{xx}(x,y,z,t)\\
-i u_{t}(x,y,z,t) - \frac{1}{2} u_{xx}(x,y,z,t)&=0\\
\end{align*}
and also setting $k = \frac{i}{2}$ we have the equation:
$$ u_{t}(x,y,z,t) - k u_{xx}(x,y,z,t)=0$$
or : $$ u_{t} - k \Delta u =0 $$

with $$u=0, \quad \text{in}\quad \partial \Omega$$
In the weak form :
Let $v \in H'_{0}(\Omega)$

\begin{align*}
\int_{\Omega}u_{t}v dV - k \int_{\Omega}\Delta u v dV&= 0 \\
\int_{\Omega}u_{t}v dV -k \int_{\Omega}\nabla u \cdot \nabla v dV& - k\int_{\partial \Omega} \nabla u \cdot \vec{n}v dS &= 0 \\
\int_{\Omega}u_{t}v +k\int_{\Omega}\nabla u \cdot \nabla v dV &=0 
\end{align*}

The problem is how I treat the  $\frac{i}{2}$ ?

Comment: just a small point; how is your Schrodinger equation in three dimensions?

Comment: $$\Delta u = \frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial z^2}$$

Comment: This $$-i u_{t}(x,t) = \frac{1}{2} u_{xx}(x,t)$$ doesn't look like the 3D Schrodinger wave equation to me; in what followed in the rest I agree, I see a Laplacian.

Comment: @fundamentalform I have edited it